# Update a progress bar while JSONDecoder is decoding a huge object, in Swift

Tags: swift, timer, progress, swift4, codable

I'm decoding several gigabytes of JSON encoded data like this

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let table = try decoder.decode([LogRow].self, from: content!)
```

where `content` is plain text. Now, this operation can take several minutes, depending on the size of `content`, and I'd like to show some kind of progress. This is a command line program, so even a periodic update on the length of `table` would be enough. The problem is that I don't see anything like a callback or something like that. I tried with a rather awkward `Timer` like this

```
var table: [LogRow]? = []
let timer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: 1.0, repeats: true) { t in
    print("\(table?.count ?? 0) rows parsed.")
}
timer.fire()
table = try decoder.decode([LogRow].self, from: content!)
timer.invalidate()
```

but that only runs once -- is it because the decoder blocks the main thread and I'm running the timer in the same thread? I'm a bit of a noob with the GCD so I'm not sure how to go about using a `DispatchQueue` for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: To perform an asynchronous task in a CLI like a `Timer` you need a **run loop**.

Comment: I kind-of assumed a repeating `Timer` would have its own internal run loop. What's your proposed solution, then?

Comment: No, your used Timer API requires to attach the timer to a runloop explicitly and the `scheduled...` API assumes there is a run loop. But CLIs don't have a run loop by default. Please google *command line interface runloop*. There are a few solutions.

Comment: How complex is your `LogRow` type? If you provide a custom `Decodable` implementation you could implement a very fine grained progress tracker.

Comment: It's massively complex, and I do provide a very detailed custom `Decodable`. How do you propose I take advantage of that? (thanks for the edits, I must have missed them while copy-pasting)

Answer (score 1):

Then can declare your timer like:

```
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.perform(#selector(self.decode), on: Thread.current, with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
        timer.invalidate()
    }
```

which means you want to trigger the `updateUI` action every second. Then you start to `decode` in a background thread and wait until done before invalidate your timer.

```
var totalDuration: Int = 0

@objc func updateUI () {
    self.currentDuration += 1
    print("------------> \(self.currentDuration)")
}

@objc func decode () {
    table = try decoder?.decode([LogRow].self, from: content!)
}
```

I added a `currentDuration` variable which could be used in your progressBar. But you must know the total duration if you need to show a percentage to your user.

Comment: what good is currentDuration when you have no idea what to check that against?

Comment: It's as good as the length of the table, so it's good enough for my use case.

Comment: But the length of the table would need to be directly related to the total time it takes to parse the entire json. But in this case I don't see how you can know how long it will take. (i.e. it needs to be based of something else as oppose to time)

Comment: But I never said I want to show anything like a percentage or an ETA, so either of the two quantities is perfectly fine with me. In fact, I roughly know how may rows the table will have, so even showing where I'm at every second is a massive improvement.

Comment: That's how I understood your question :)

Comment: fair enough maybe I should have just strictly looked at the question at hand. Unfortunately I can't withdraw my downvote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Without a run loop  this won't work at all in a command line interface.