# Finding progress of decoder.decode codable in Swift

Tags: swift, codable

I want to create a progress indicator for downloading contacts from an API.

I am using codable, and have thousand of records.

```
    HTTPManager.shared.get(urlString: ContactManager.createURL(), completionBlock:  {(data: Data?) -> Void in
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let d = data{

            do {
                let userData = try decoder.decode([Contact].self, from: d)
                self.isFetchingData = false
                print ("done", userData)
            } catch let error {
                print ("Error in reading data", error)
            }
        }

    }
    )
```

For information here is my Contact Struct

```
struct Contact : Codable {
    let firstname : String?
    let url : String?
    let lastname : String?
    let profilepic : String?
    let favorite: Bool?
    let id: Int?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case firstname = "first_name"
        case url
        case lastname = "last_name"
        case profilepic = "profile_pic"
        case favorite = "favorite"
        case id
    }
}
```

This is not homework, I've looked through the documentation for JSONdecoder and I know a solution by using JSONSerialization. I want to know if there is anyway to do this using codable and have done research to do with this.

Basically how can I know which contact decoder is working on at any point in time, so then I can send this information to the UI with d.count so I can display the progress to the user?

Comment: I am just curious: How long does it take to decode the complete JSON (*after* the data has been fetched from the server)?

Comment: I see what you're saying - it's quick. The progress indicator seems to have been to keep the display locked while waiting for images to load for a UITableView - seems to not be a great implementation as I think I would be better to use SDWebImage for that or similar.

Comment: That is what I assumed. Actually it *is* possible to report progress from the JSONDecoder, but that would not solve the real problem, as it seems.

Comment: Is that solution this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809851/update-a-progress-bar-while-jsondecoder-is-decoding-a-huge-object-in-swift

Comment: No, it isn't. I can post it later, if you are still interested.

Comment: I am interested, if you post it I'll definitely take a look...thanks...